# FFG is based on pBFT which does not scale! How Ethereum still supports Millions of validators?

Tags: consensus

As long as I know FFG is based on pBFT algorithm which has finality but which can not scale.
How Ethereum manages to reach consensus with node count > 100 ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not be so adamant about saying FFG is based on pBFT rather than just BFT.

But to answer your question, Ethereum manages to have this humongous amount of validators using two factors:

- delay vote aggregation
- BLS signature

### Delay vote aggregation

This refers to the amount of time given for validators to emit their vote and aggregate it. Conversely to pBFT, in Ethereum, the vote for finalization needs at least an entire epoch to be issued and gathered. This allows for reducing the burden of communication by extending the time of discussion.

### BLS signature

This type of signature is what permits the number of votes sent by validators at the same time during each slot. There is a nice way to combine a lot of signatures and verify them extremely quickly. For more info, check this [great explanation](https://hackmd.io/@benjaminion/bls12-381#Aggregation) done by Ben Edington.